# Why does VertexComponent not return all vertices at distance <= 3?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

Take the following triangle lattice graph (see `edges` definition below):

```
g = Graph[edges, DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us try to find the vertices reachable from vertex `50` in at most 3 steps. My understanding is that we can use [`VertexComponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexComponent.html) for this.

Let's try:

```
HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, VertexComponent[g, 50, 3]], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Why are 75, 42 and 69 missed?** Their distance is also 3:

```
GraphDistance[g, 50, #] & /@ {75, 42, 69}
(* {3, 3, 3} *)
```

What is happening here?  Am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug?

---

```
edges = {1 -> 12, 2 -> 13, 3 -> 14, 4 -> 15, 5 -> 16, 6 -> 17, 
   7 -> 18, 8 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 10 -> 21, 11 -> 22, 12 -> 23, 13 -> 24, 
   14 -> 25, 15 -> 26, 16 -> 27, 17 -> 28, 18 -> 29, 19 -> 30, 
   20 -> 31, 21 -> 32, 22 -> 33, 23 -> 34, 24 -> 35, 25 -> 36, 
   26 -> 37, 27 -> 38, 28 -> 39, 29 -> 40, 30 -> 41, 31 -> 42, 
   32 -> 43, 33 -> 44, 34 -> 45, 35 -> 46, 36 -> 47, 37 -> 48, 
   38 -> 49, 39 -> 50, 40 -> 51, 41 -> 52, 42 -> 53, 43 -> 54, 
   44 -> 55, 45 -> 56, 46 -> 57, 47 -> 58, 48 -> 59, 49 -> 60, 
   50 -> 61, 51 -> 62, 52 -> 63, 53 -> 64, 54 -> 65, 55 -> 66, 
   56 -> 67, 57 -> 68, 58 -> 69, 59 -> 70, 60 -> 71, 61 -> 72, 
   62 -> 73, 63 -> 74, 64 -> 75, 65 -> 76, 66 -> 77, 67 -> 78, 
   68 -> 79, 69 -> 80, 70 -> 81, 71 -> 82, 72 -> 83, 73 -> 84, 
   74 -> 85, 75 -> 86, 76 -> 87, 77 -> 88, 78 -> 89, 79 -> 90, 
   80 -> 91, 81 -> 92, 82 -> 93, 83 -> 94, 84 -> 95, 85 -> 96, 
   86 -> 97, 87 -> 98, 88 -> 99, 89 -> 100, 90 -> 101, 91 -> 102, 
   92 -> 103, 93 -> 104, 94 -> 105, 95 -> 106, 96 -> 107, 97 -> 108, 
   98 -> 109, 99 -> 110, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 
   6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 10 -> 11, 12 -> 13, 13 -> 14, 
   14 -> 15, 15 -> 16, 16 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 18 -> 19, 19 -> 20, 
   20 -> 21, 21 -> 22, 23 -> 24, 24 -> 25, 25 -> 26, 26 -> 27, 
   27 -> 28, 28 -> 29, 29 -> 30, 30 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 32 -> 33, 
   34 -> 35, 35 -> 36, 36 -> 37, 37 -> 38, 38 -> 39, 39 -> 40, 
   40 -> 41, 41 -> 42, 42 -> 43, 43 -> 44, 45 -> 46, 46 -> 47, 
   47 -> 48, 48 -> 49, 49 -> 50, 50 -> 51, 51 -> 52, 52 -> 53, 
   53 -> 54, 54 -> 55, 56 -> 57, 57 -> 58, 58 -> 59, 59 -> 60, 
   60 -> 61, 61 -> 62, 62 -> 63, 63 -> 64, 64 -> 65, 65 -> 66, 
   67 -> 68, 68 -> 69, 69 -> 70, 70 -> 71, 71 -> 72, 72 -> 73, 
   73 -> 74, 74 -> 75, 75 -> 76, 76 -> 77, 78 -> 79, 79 -> 80, 
   80 -> 81, 81 -> 82, 82 -> 83, 83 -> 84, 84 -> 85, 85 -> 86, 
   86 -> 87, 87 -> 88, 89 -> 90, 90 -> 91, 91 -> 92, 92 -> 93, 
   93 -> 94, 94 -> 95, 95 -> 96, 96 -> 97, 97 -> 98, 98 -> 99, 
   100 -> 101, 101 -> 102, 102 -> 103, 103 -> 104, 104 -> 105, 
   105 -> 106, 106 -> 107, 107 -> 108, 108 -> 109, 109 -> 110, 
   2 -> 12, 2 -> 14, 4 -> 14, 4 -> 16, 6 -> 16, 6 -> 18, 8 -> 18, 
   8 -> 20, 10 -> 20, 10 -> 22, 13 -> 23, 13 -> 25, 15 -> 25, 
   15 -> 27, 17 -> 27, 17 -> 29, 19 -> 29, 19 -> 31, 21 -> 31, 
   21 -> 33, 24 -> 34, 24 -> 36, 26 -> 36, 26 -> 38, 28 -> 38, 
   28 -> 40, 30 -> 40, 30 -> 42, 32 -> 42, 32 -> 44, 35 -> 45, 
   35 -> 47, 37 -> 47, 37 -> 49, 39 -> 49, 39 -> 51, 41 -> 51, 
   41 -> 53, 43 -> 53, 43 -> 55, 46 -> 56, 46 -> 58, 48 -> 58, 
   48 -> 60, 50 -> 60, 50 -> 62, 52 -> 62, 52 -> 64, 54 -> 64, 
   54 -> 66, 57 -> 67, 57 -> 69, 59 -> 69, 59 -> 71, 61 -> 71, 
   61 -> 73, 63 -> 73, 63 -> 75, 65 -> 75, 65 -> 77, 68 -> 78, 
   68 -> 80, 70 -> 80, 70 -> 82, 72 -> 82, 72 -> 84, 74 -> 84, 
   74 -> 86, 76 -> 86, 76 -> 88, 79 -> 89, 79 -> 91, 81 -> 91, 
   81 -> 93, 83 -> 93, 83 -> 95, 85 -> 95, 85 -> 97, 87 -> 97, 
   87 -> 99, 90 -> 100, 90 -> 102, 92 -> 102, 92 -> 104, 94 -> 104, 
   94 -> 106, 96 -> 106, 96 -> 108, 98 -> 108, 98 -> 110};
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You could use `AdjacencyMatrix` instead as a workaround.

Comment: @CarlWoll You mean `AdjacencyList`, right?  It does basically the same thing, except it does not include the original vertex in the list.

Comment: No, I was thinking of something like `MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3] . initialVector` or probably better `MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3, initialVector]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something seems broken. As a workaround you might do something like:

```
gg[1] := NeighborhoodGraph[g, 50, 1]

gg[k_] := NeighborhoodGraph[g, gg[k - 1], 1]

HighlightGraph[g, gg[3], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate implementation of [`VertexComponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexComponent) using [`AdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix):

```
vertexComponent[g_, v_, n___] := Module[{vec = initialVector[g, v, n]},
    ivertexComponent[g, v, vec, n] /; vec =!= $Failed
] /; ArgumentCountQ[vertexComponent, Length @ Hold[g, v, n], 2, 3]

initialVector[g_, v_, n___] := Module[{vl = VertexList[g]},
    Which[
        MemberQ[vl, v],
        Boole[Thread[vl == v]],

        ListQ[v] && ContainsAll[vl, v],
        Boole[MemberQ[v, #]& /@ vl],

        True, 
        Message[vertexComponent::inv, HoldForm[OutputForm @ vertexComponent[g,v,n]], v, "vertex"];
        $Failed
    ]
]

ivertexComponent[g_, v_, vec_, n___] := Module[{p, vl = VertexList[g], a},
    p = Replace[{n},
        {
        {i_Integer?NonNegative} :> i,
        {} -> Length[vl],
        {x_} :> (Message[vertexComponent::inv, HoldForm[OutputForm @ vertexComponent[g,v,n]], x, "parameter"]; $Failed)
        }
    ];

    (
        a = AdjacencyMatrix[g] + IdentityMatrix[Length[vl], SparseArray];
        Pick[vl, Unitize @ MatrixPower[a, p, vec], 1]
    ) /; p =!= $Failed
]
```

For your example:

```
vertexComponent[g, 50, 3]
```

> {17, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 82, 83, 84}

Comparison:

```
Complement[vertexComponent[g, 50, 3], VertexComponent[g, 50, 3]]
```

> {42, 69, 75}